# Cropping the minimum sized rectangle of a shape from an image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am making a card recognition project on MATLAB and I am stuck at this point. There are images of cards and on an image I want to define the smallest rectangle that takes the card inside. Example like below

Original image

[image: ORIGINAL IMAGE]

Converted image

[image: AIMED IMAGE]

I am currently able to convert the image to black and white (leaves me only the cards white spaces), I want to define the rectangles by the whole white spaces. E.g., if I have 3 non-lapping cards in my image, I want to have 3 images like above (doesn't matter if another cards edge appears on the image, the important part is that rectangle must pass through the edges of the selected card).

I have tried edge definition methods but wasn't successful. Thanks for your help already.

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Previous code is irrelevant to my main problem (just conversions for black and white).
You can consider that you have the first image as an rgb image and you want to get the second image (or at least the borders).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you use `regionprops` function from the image processing tool box, i.e.,

```
bb = regionprops(yourImage, 'boundingbox');
```

which will return the bounding box. There is a nice MATWORKS video [here](https://www.mathworks.com/videos/image-processing-made-easy-81718.html) and you can jump to about minute 26 for what you need.

Comment: Thank you so much. That solved my problem perfectly.